# How to avoid activator executing compile task twice upon accessing Play page?

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

I am trying to run a custom task before compilation of a Play 2.3 application. I have this in my `build.sbt` file:

```
lazy val helloTask = TaskKey[Unit]("hello", "hello")

helloTask := {
  println("hello test")
}

(compile in Compile) <<= (compile in Compile) dependsOn helloTask
```

When I run `activator ~run` and then open a page in the browser, I get the following output:

```
C:\Development\test>activator ~run
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Development\test\project
[info] Set current project to play (in build file:/C:/Development/test/)

--- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

hello test
[success] Compiled in 418ms
hello test
hello test
[info] play - Application started (Dev)
```

It seems my custom task is running three times. Is there a way I can avoid this?

Comment: Interesting. It appears that loading a page triggers `compile` twice. [I'd report an issue](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues).

Comment: BTW, use the shorter version `taskKey` to define a new task - `lazy val hello = taskKey[Unit]("My custom hello task")`.

Comment: Eventually.... The. New release may fix this

Comment: Would this same issue cause assets tasks to be compiled twice as well?

Comment: Any update? We can observe the same issue (play 2.3.8, sbt 13.7, scala 2.11.5). In our case, the task gets executed over and over again.

Comment: I think it should be: `lazy val helloTask = TaskKey[Unit]("helloTask", "hello")`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I found solution.

In Sbt you have three [Scopes by configuration axis](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Scopes.html#Scoping+by+configuration+axis) :

> - Compile which defines the main build (src/main/scala).
> - Test which defines how to build tests (src/test/scala).
> - Runtime which defines the classpath for the run task.

You must use *Runtime* instead of *Compile*. It should looks like this:

```
lazy val helloTask = taskKey[Unit]("hello")

helloTask := println("hello test")

(compile in Runtime) <<= (compile in Runtime) dependsOn helloTask
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the first result on google so I would like to post my current solution to the problem which actually works with play 2.8 and a multi project build. It is slightly modified. The proposed [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33046270/1029251) by @bartholomaios results in a compile loop for me.

```
lazy val helloTask = taskKey[Unit]("hello")
    
helloTask := println("hello test")

lazy val module1: Project = (project in file("modules/module1"))

# Run a task before sbt module1/run
((module1 / run) in Compile) := (((module1 / run) in Compile) dependsOn Compile / helloTask).evaluated

# Run a task before sbt module1/docker:stage
((module1 / stage) in Docker) := (((module1 / stage) in Docker) dependsOn Compile / helloTask).value
```